# Tracking a 301 redirect for a campaign onto a 3rd party server

Tags: analytics, iis

So we are running a campaign with a qr code that has some google analytics query strings embedded. We've setup our IIS to do a 301 redirect on the folder that sends the user off to a 3rd party CRM.

Do we need to process the query string using some type of backend with google analytics before we redirect? Do I need to remove the 301 redtirect from iis and do the redirect based on my code?  What's the best approach for this?

this is my query string format:

http://www.qrstuff.com/?utm_source=flyer&utm_medium=qrcode&utm_content=apr2011&
utm_campaign=spring

Answer (score 1):

It depends what's your goal and who's the GA owner.

If you want to track this UTMs on your side, yes you should send it to GA before redirection. Read about [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#page)

If you want to pass this UTMs to 3rd party server, answer is redirection with [querystrings](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4678/permanent-301-redirect-with-querystring-in-iis/)

Comment: Our goal is to track if they come from qr code. We are the GA owner.  They are hitting our redirect on our domain and then redirecting them to a 3rd party form on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use GA's measurement protocol. Here is the dev guide on that: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

You can keep the redirect setup on IIS to send the 301 response, but before sending the redirect use that protocol to send the hit payload.